# Access private facebook group's posts using Graph API ( v 7.0 )

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get private groups posts by using graph api v7.0 by unfortunately i did not get posts returned an error Graph returned an error: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (SAAME)

```
    try {
    // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->get(
        '/SAAME/feed',
        '{access-token}'
    );
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
//$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

$data = (array) $response;

var_dump ($data);
```

Comment: You can't query by username like the error say.

Comment: @WizKid any idea how to get private group posts ?

Comment: what is the use case? are you trying with an access token of a group admin? content of private groups should not pop up somewhere else, so i guess you cannot get the data easily with the api - for very good reasons.

Comment: @luschn i m using user access token trying to get private groups posts. If i did not get through api what's the process i follow tell me any you have?

Comment: that is not a use case, what do you actually want to do with the group posts? and again, did you try with a user token of a group admin?

Comment: no i am not using group admin user token and i using token of user who the member of private group

Comment: i am pretty sure that is not possible, for the reason i mentioned

Comment: @luschn its means if i want to get private group posts so i must the admin of the group then i access data of posts no other option i have to get posts. Its correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215560/discussion-between-zaheer-bashir-and-luschn).

Answer (score 4):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/group/feed

Check out the requirements, especially the bold ones:

- **Your app must be approved for the Groups API feature.**
- **The app must be installed on the Group. (can only be done as group admin)**
- A User access token. (i assume any user token of a group member is ok)